# Problems Creating a custom startup file in phusion passenger for node

Tags: node.js, cpanel, passenger, startup, phusion

I follow this tutorial

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360057519553-How-to-create-a-custom-NodeJS-startup-file-

But when I set up my files and do everything like the tutorial the startup file is still not pointing to the correct file.

This the location of my file

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/dacosta2022/aquitulugar.com.nodejs.conf
```

Also I try

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/dacosta2022/aquitulugar.com/nodejs.conf
```

And this is the file content

```
DocumentRoot /user/aquitulugar.com/server/src
# Use server.js as the startup file (entry point file) for
# your Node.js application, instead of the default app.js
PassengerStartupFile index.js
PassengerAppType node
PassengerAppRoot /aquitulugar.com
```

Also I Rebuild and restart the Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Probably wrong on this, but looking at your notes for the `PassengerStartupFile` you say it should be `server.js`, but the code says `index.js`.